# SQL - Condições diferentes na mesma coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados

O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:

```
select

coluna1, --(Mesma coluna)
coluna1  --(Mesma coluna)

from
    tabela1
```

O que eu preciso é que a primeira coluna1 só mostre valores específicos como apenas laranjas e a segunda coluna1 mostre apenas valores específicos como maçãs. A coluna tem em seu conteúdo as duas frutas.

Answer (score 0):

Certo, se eu entendi corretamente, você quer selecionar a mesma coluna duas vezes na consulta, mas mostrar valores específicos para cada uma delas. Para fazer isso, você pode usar a cláusula CASE na consulta.

Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN coluna1 = 'laranjas' THEN coluna1 ELSE NULL END AS coluna1_especifica1,
  CASE WHEN coluna1 = 'maçãs' THEN coluna1 ELSE NULL END AS coluna1_especifica2
FROM tabela1;
```

Nesse exemplo, a consulta seleciona a coluna1 duas vezes, mas usa a clausula CASE para exibir apenas cada valor específico. No primeiro CASE, a coluna Coluna1 é exibida apenas se seu valor for laranja, e no segundo CASE, é exibida apenas se o valor da coluna for maçã. Outros valores da Coluna1 exibem NULL.

Comment: E o perguntador some.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi bem sua necessidade, mas você pode usar duas vezes a mesma tabela

select

A.coluna1, --(Mesma coluna)
B.coluna1  --(Mesma coluna)

from
tabela1 A
tabela1 B

No where vc relaciona as colunas chave entre as tabela1 e especifica o que quer que liste como coluna1 em ambos os casos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).